# docker CMD run supervisord in background

Tags: postgresql, docker, supervisord, dockerfile

is there any way to run supervisord in the background. means start the process and get out of shell.

I have a docker file where i try to run a script that suppose to start the postgresql and then get out. so I have a process running and i can create users. 
Docker command

```
CMD  ["/runprocess.sh"]
```

script runproccess.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
supervisord -c "/etc/supervisord.conf"
```

I have also tried to run it in background, but no luck

```
#!/bin/bash
supervisord -c "/etc/supervisord.conf" &
```

supervisord starts the process and just stays on screen for ever. 
i want it to run the process and get out. so I can run other part of my script.

Comment: How do you run your container after the build? Please send the full command.

Comment: Supervisord already runs in the background by default. Something else must be at play. Can you post the Dockerfile along with the command using the run it?

Answer (score 3):

you can remove setting nodaemon or set it to false in supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=false ; Docker利用ではtrueにする必要あり
```

this will make supervisor start in background.